# Creating a serializable superclass

Tags: c++, serialization, polymorphism

In my project I need to be able to serialize objects into XML files (I use TinyXML for this).
I want to create a `XMLSerializable` superclass from which any class that needs to be serializable inherits.

I am struggling to come up with a clean way of performing the deserializing step (loading an object from a file). For `XMLSerializable::serialize`, the signature seems clear to me:

```
virtual tinyxml2::XMLElement* serialize() = 0;
```

I could implement `deserialize` in a similar fashion:

```
virtual bool deserialize(const char* filename) = 0; // returns true on success
```

This however forces me to first instantiate any inherited class before calling `deserialize`, as such:

```
ConcreteClass instance;
instance.deserialize("settings.xml");
```

This is cumbersome, especially if `ConcreteClass` does not have a default constructor.
I cannot make `deserialize` static, as it couldn't be overridden then by `ConcreteClass`.

What is the clean solution here? Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't really deserialize an object without a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to deserialize an object without an default constructor as mentioned in the comments.

Furthemore your question is not realy clear, please show more "real" code.

I dont actually get the problem, you want to have a static method take a static, if you want to adict it to an object you obviously need to create it :o